# Getting 404 not found error when including node_module scripts and styles in index.html inside src

Tags: html, angularjs, node-modules

Given below the code snippet of referring the scripts and the screen shot of the error occurring while including the scripts and styles.

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33HSO.png)

Also given below the folder structure of the mentioned code snippet

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mcMl.png)

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "dynamic-location",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An angular directive for listing of the objects and tracking their events in map",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \\\"Error: no test specified\\\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "dynamic",
    "objects",
    "event",
    "tracking",
    "map"
  ],
  "author": "Subba",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.3",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.4",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^2.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-serve": "^0.1.6",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using Bower as a package manager, for your app dependencies?

Comment: No, I'm using node itself for app dependencies

Comment: can you share the image of package.json and bower.json, so that it would be helpful to figure out your issue

Comment: Package json has been updated in the query and I'm not intending to use bower for this app

Comment: try running from bower modules <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

Comment: Is it not possible to do with node itself other than using bower?

Comment: In your Folder Structure photo, the `node_modules` folder is red, which probably means it's excluded from your project. Is there some kind of right click option that says something like "Include in project?" I've never used WebStorm...